# g++ Error:expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4

i have this piece of code.what i have tried is to subclass `QGraphicsScene` to reimplement its `keyPressEvent()` method.By the way i had to choose this peculiar implementation(especially `typedef` portion ) for this thing, to meet up the issue of compatibilty with the other parts of the code.

**keypress.h**

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

class Canvas;

typedef struct{
    int id;
    int pid;
    Canvas *qgc;

}scene;

class Canvas: public QGraphicsScene {

    private:
        scene *gc;

    public:
        Canvas(Scene* gc, QWidget *parent=0);

    protected:
        void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e);
};
```

**keypress.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QKeyEvent>

#include "keypress.h"

Canvas::Canvas( Scene* gc, QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    this->gc=gc;
}

void Canvas::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
   if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape) {  
   qApp->quit();
   } 
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "keypress.h"
#include <QGraphicsView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);  

  Scene *s;
  Canvas *canvas=new Canvas(s);
  canvas->addText("Hello");

  QGraphicsView view(canvas);
  view.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

whenever i am trying  to compile this program,i am getting error

```
In file included from keypress.cpp:4:
keypress.h:29: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
keypress.cpp:6: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
make: *** [keypress.o] Error 1
```

what is the problem in my code?

Comment: Your typedef says `scene`, but you use `Scene` in several places. Is this intended? Note that identifiers in C++ are case-sensitive.

Comment: According to your error message, keypress.h contains at least 29 lines. The keypress.h you posted only contains 24 lines.

Comment: First, at `Canvas *canvas=new Canvas(s);`, s is non initialized. Then, you mix Scene and scene. Correct this and, as said before, give us the complete keypress.h.